# Putty - AWS - connection timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, putty

I am using Putty to connect to my AWS instances. All is working well. The only problem is that if my laptop that manages the instance goes into stand-by mode (unfortunately default corporate installation setting) my instance gives a connnection error as well and stops the execution of the script. Is it not the whole purpose of AWS that the instance can work in a disconnected manner? Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: This really isn't an AWS or Putty question, as indicated by the tags, but a question about basic Linux/Unix usage.

Answer (score 3):

If you starts your script from the remote shell, the process is then attached to this shell, and when your laptop is going to stand-by mode, the network is being disconnected to reduce battery usage, and the process which was executed from your remote shell is stopping as well.

What you can do is to detach your process from being child process of your remote shell. You can start it like that:

`/path/to/my_script.sh & | disown %1`

> `&` puts the job in the background, that is, makes it block on
>   attempting to read input, and makes the shell not wait for its
>   completion.
>
> `disown` removes the process from the shell's job control, but it
>   still leaves it connected to the terminal. One of the results is that
>   the shell won't send it a SIGHUP. Obviously, it can only be applied to
>   background jobs, because you cannot enter it when a foreground job is
>   running.